# Python Kind of "State Variable"

Tags: python, variables, types

Does anyone know, if its possible to define a data type in Python to do the following:

```
something = variable.OPEN 
if something == variable.OPEN:
    print('open')
elif something == variable.BLOCKED:
    print('blocked')
elif something == variable.CLOSED:
    print('closed')
```

I know that I did something familiar a couple of years ago, but I cant remember how :(

Thanks!

Comment: Are you thinking of an `Enum`?

Comment: Oh deer! Yes, it was Enums! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for Enums in Python.

Thanks to @Samwise